# typeorm select OneToMany entity by last createdAt

Tags: javascript, postgresql, typescript, typeorm

Have quite typical problem i think - what is the proper way to select the latest entity of `OneToMany` relationship by typeorm? db is `postgresql`

```
@Entity('hubs')
export class Hub {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
    id: string;

    @Column()
    ip: string;

    @OneToMany(type => HubStatus, statusLog => statusLog.hub, { cascade: true })
    statusLog: Array<HubStatus>;

    @UpdateDateColumn()
    updatedAt: Date;

    lastStatus: any;

    @AfterLoad()
    async getStatus() {
          const query = createQueryBuilder(Hub)
            .leftJoinAndSelect("Hub.statusLog", "statusLog", 'Hub.id = :id', { id: this.id })
            //.addSelect("MAX(statusLog.createdAt)")
            //.andHaving('statusLog.createdAt = MAX(statusLog.createdAt)');
            //.andWhere('Hub.id = :id', { id: this.id })
            //.andWhere('statusLog.createdAt = MAX(statusLog.createdAt)');

          //assign part of result to this.lastStatus
    }
}

@Entity('hub-status')
export class HubStatus {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: string;

    @Column({type: 'json')
    somecolumn

    @ManyToOne(type => Hub, hub => hub.statusLog)
    hub: Hub;

    @CreateDateColumn()
    createdAt: Date;
}
```

i want to get the latest (by createdAt) associated `HubStatus` in `@AfterLoad` block. `max` can't be used in `where` clause, i also tried multiple options of using `max` in `select` and they fail for different reasons.

Answer (score 0):

I made it this way, so it does work for development purposes at least:

```
@AfterLoad()
async getStatus() {
    const innerSelect = getRepository(HubStatus)
        .createQueryBuilder()
        .select('id')
        .where('HubStatus.hub.id = :id')
        .orderBy('id', "DESC")
        .limit(1);

    const query = createQueryBuilder(Hub)
        .select('somecolumn')
        .leftJoin(`Hub.statusLog`, "statusLog", `statusLog.id = (${innerSelect.getSql()})`, { id: this.id })

    this.lastStatus = (await query.getRawOne()).somecolumn;
}
```

but the questions is still open - there will be possibly millions of entries in `HubStatus` and if think that `ORDER BY` + `LIMIT 1` solution isn't going to perform well in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to use a `leftJoinAndMapOne` query builer method and `NOT EXISTS` SQL condition in your join condition to test for later entities:

```
      const query = createQueryBuilder(Hub)
        .leftJoinAndMapOne('Hub.statusLog', HubStatus, 'statusLog',
         `Hub.id = statusLog.hubId AND NOT EXISTS (
         SELECT 1 FROM hub-status hs1 WHERE hs1.hubId = Hub.id AND hs1.id > statusLog.id)`,
        ).getMany()
```